# ¿error llamar estructuras en c++?

Tags: c++, c

tengo un error en el código pero no se porque, creo que el error es en el tipo de variable que estoy usando en las estructuras

[image: error1]
[image: error2]
[image: error3]

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <array>
using namespace std;

 struct ussers{

  char usser1 [4] = "root";
  char usser2 [4] = "root";
  char usser3 [4] = "root";
  char usser4 [5] = "admin";
  char usser5 [4] = "root";
  char usser6 [4] = "root";
  char usser7 [4] = "root";
  char usser8 [4] = "root";
  char usser9 [4] = "root";
  char usser10[4] = "root";
  char usser11[7] = "support";
  char usser12[4] = "root";
  char usser13[5] = "admin";
  char usser14[4] = "root";
  char usser15[4] = "root";
  char usser16[4] = "user";
  char usser17[5] = "admin";
  char usser18[4] = "root";
  char usser19[5] = "admin";
  char usser20[4] = "root";
  char usser21[5] = "admin";
  char usser22[5] = "admin";
  char usser23[4] = "root";
  char usser24[4] = "root";
  char usser25[4] = "root";
  char usser26[4] = "root";
  char usser27[7] = "service";
  char usser28[5] = "guest";
  char usser29[5] = "guest";
  char usser30[5] = "guest";
  char usser31[6] = "admin1";
  char usser32[6] = "666666";
  char usser33[6] = "888888";
  char usser34[4] = "ubnt ";
  char usser35[4] = "root";
  char usser36[4] = "root";
  char usser37[4] = "root";
  char usser38[4] = "root";
  char usser39[4] = "root";
  char usser40[4] = "root"; 
  char usser41[4] = "root";
  char usser42[4] = "root";
  char usser43[4] = "root";
  char usser44[4] = "root";
  char usser45[4] = "root";
  char usser46[4] = "root";
  char usser47[4] = "root";
  char usser48[4] = "root";
  char usser49[5] = "admin";
  char usser50[5] = "admin";
  char usser51[5] = "admin";
  char usser52[5] = "admin";
  char usser53[5] = "admin";
  char usser54[5] = "admin";
  char usser55[5] = "admin";
  char usser56[5] = "admin";
  char usser57[5] = "admin";
  char usser58[5] = "admin";
  char usser59[5] = "admin";
  char usser60[5] = "admin";
  char usser61[4] = "tech";
  char usser62[6] = "mother";

 }usser *punter_usser = &usser;

 struct passwords{

   char password1[] ="xc3511";
   char password2[] ="vizxv";
   char password3[] ="admin";
   char password4[] ="admin";
   char password5[] ="888888";
   char password6[] ="xmhdipc";
   char password7[] ="default";
   char password8[] ="juantech";
   char password9[] ="123456";
   char password10[] ="54321";
   char password11[] ="support";
   char password12[] ="";
   char password13[] ="password";
   char password14[] ="root";
   char password15[] ="12345";
   char password16[] ="user";
   char password17[] ="";
   char password18[] ="pass";
   char password19[] ="admin1234";
   char password20[] ="1111";
   char password21[] ="smcadmin";
   char password22[] ="1111";
   char password23[] ="666666";
   char password24[] ="password";
   char password25[] ="1234";
   char password26[] ="klv123";
   char password27[] ="admin";
   char password28[] ="service";
   char password29[] ="supervisor";
   char password30[] ="guest";
   char password31[] ="12345";
   char password32[] ="12345";
   char password33[] ="password";
   char password34[] ="1234";
   char password35[] ="666666";
   char password36[] ="888888";
   char password37[] ="ubnt";
   char password38[] ="klv1234";
   char password39[] ="Zte521";
   char password40[] ="hi3518";
   char password41[] ="jvbzd";   
   char password42[] ="anko";
   char password43[] ="zlxx.";
   char password44[] ="7ujMko0vizxv";
   char password45[] ="7ujMko0admin";
   char password46[] ="system";
   char password47[] ="ikwb";
   char password48[] ="dreambox";
   char password49[] ="user";
   char password50[] ="realtek";
   char password51[] ="00000000";
   char password52[] ="1111111";
   char password53[] ="1234";
   char password54[] ="12345";
   char password55[] ="54321";
   char password56[] ="123456";
   char password57[] ="7ujMko0admin";
   char password58[] ="1234";
   char password59[] ="pass";
   char password60[] ="meinsm";
   char password61[] ="tech";
   char password62[] ="fucker";

   }password *punter_password = &password;
   
   

int main(){
  
  cout<<"[scanner:]"<<punter_password->password1;
  cout<<"[scanner:]"<<punter_password->password2;
  cout<<"[scanner:]"<<punter_password->password3;
  cout<<"[scanner:]"<<punter_usser->usser1;
  cout<<"[scanner:]"<<punter_usser->usser2;
  cout<<"[scanner:]"<<punter_usser->usser3;
  

  return 0;
 }
```

Comment: Disculpa que lo diga, pero le quitaste la razon de existir a los arrays, mejor quedaria si hicieras:`char* users[7]={"root","root"};`

Comment: `char usser1 [4] = "root";` Date cuenta de que no estas dejando espacio para el caracter nulo. Cuando trates de usarlo el programa leera `root` y seguira de largo hasta encontrar un `\0`. Dependiendo de tu compilador, aqui puedes tener un error de compilacion.

Comment: Y que es lo que se supone que hacen las lineas: `} usser *punter_usser = &usser;` y `} password *punter_password = &password;`. No tienen ningun sentido. De estas ya tienes un error de compilacion.

Comment: @Pablochaches es un puntero que señala la la variable password

Comment: Entonces te falta una coma entre `password` y `*punter_password`. Igual con la otra.\

Comment: @Pablochaches gracias pero ahora solo me queda un error en comun ,hay un error codigo.cpp:143:9: error: initializer for flexible array member 'char passwords::password62 []'

Comment: Es por la mala palabra, tienes que quitarla

Comment: Es broma, el error que tengas deveria solucionarse dandole un tamaño igual que como los tienes en el struct de arriba.